# Putting unix dates into angular table

Tags: angularjs

I want to format my date from `1499992000` to `Fri Jul 14 2017`

```
<td> {{ new Date(vm.checkinDate*1000) }} </td>
```

Is there a way to do this directly on the page? Or will I have to do it in the controller?

All I get now is:

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Date' is an unexpected token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

Angular swill be able to parse a unix date into a date using the build in filters

```
<td> {{vm.checkinDate*1000 | date : 'EEE MMM dd yyyy' }} </td>
```